# Is the Talisman Upgrade Pack worthwhile?

Tags: expansions, talisman

I own the Talisman 4th edition game published by Black Industries. Talisman revised 4th edition is now published by Fantasy Flight Games. I have seen an upgrade pack that is supposed to make the 4th edition game compatible with the revised 4th edition and its expansion packs.

The upgrade pack contains:

- Rulesheet
- Over 160 Cards
- 14 Character Cards and Figures
- 4 Plastic Toad Figures
- 36 Fate Tokens

My questions are:

1. Is this upgrade pack worth purchasing? Retail is  approx. $20 USD and that seems like it could be a bit much for no new content.
2. Does the new rulesheet address all the typos and misprints in the 4th edition rules and board?
3. Can someone with the 4th edition use the revised 4th edition expansions without this upgrade? I know Fantasy Flight would say, "No way," but I want to know what things have changed that would make the expansions not work right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. "No new content" is wrong. There is a small change with big impact in the FFG rules... fate points. (Reroll failed rolls.)
2. Most of them.
3. Yep. The only change in rules is the addition of fate points.

The cards are, IIRC, all errata items.

Comment: FWIW, this upgrade pack has long since become out-of-print. I would go back in time to get it if I could. There are enough fate coin things on the cards in the expansions that you really need to have them. At this point it's cheaper to just buy the base game again (which I don't really want to do).